# how to set a javascript calculate function to wait until it sees a value in another field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a function that calculates (adds) values from 2 other fields and diplays the results in a third field. This works perfectly. However, I now need this calculate function to "wait" until it sees a value populated in a separate date field. Once this date field has a value then the calculate function can display the results. See current calculate function below.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```js
function Calculate() {
  var item1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step1amount").getValue();
  if (item1 == null) {
    item1 = 0;
  }

  var item2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step2amount").getValue();
  if (item2 == null) {
    item2 = 0;
  }

  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item1 + item2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pseudo code:

```
if(dateFieldHasValue)
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item1 + item2);
}
```

Just call your function `onchange` of the date field...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I added the if statement you suggested. See code below. However now I'm getting "calculate is undefined" message.

Comment: sorry here you go                                                                                   function Calculate() 
{

    var item1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step1amount").getValue();
    if (item1 == null) {
        item1 = 0;
    }

    var item2 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_step2amount").getValue();
    if (item2 == null) {
        item2 = 0;
    }

if(new_steponecontractrecieved.value=='') 
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totalamountcollected").setValue(item1 + item2);

}

Comment: @BMergen I don't see the function closing tag `(item1 + item2); }**}**` also I think u would want `if(new_steponecontractrecieved.value!='')` instead of `if(new_steponecontractrecieved.value=='')`...